# How are absolute risks estimated by the Cox model?

Tags: regression, cox-model, relative-risk, absolute-risk

According to my modest understanding, the Cox model is all about estimating hazard ratios, relative measures of risk. However, it is possible (in R using e.g. the packages `pec` or `peperr`) to estimate absolute risks by a Cox model.

How is this done mathematically?

Comment: The absolute risk at time t given a covariate vector x_i can be estimated as exp(-lambda(t)exp(x_i'beta), where lambda(t) is the Breslow estimator for the cumulative hazard. I don't know how this is derived though.